# lucee 5.x ListEach doesn't seem to be able to access local var scope?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I can't seem to access the `local` scope within my ListEach:

```
writeDump(local.woCoreID); // outputs expected values
//  LOOP OVER LIST AND SEPARATE TEXT FROM INTEGERS
ListEach(local.__userSuppliedWorkoutTagList, function (item) {
    writeDump(item) //  outputs expected values
    writeDump(local.woCoreID); // key [woCoreID] doesn't exist
});
```

when I try to access the local.woCoreID, I get an error message, `key [woCoreID] doesn't exist`. Why is that when I can dump it before the ListEach and I see the value is there. What am I missing here?

I'm using Lucee 5.x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `function` has its own `local` scope. If you want to the *outer* scope, you must make a reference to it:

```
var outerLocal = local;

ListEach(local.__userSuppliedWorkoutTagList, function (item) {
    writeDump(item);
    writeDump(outerLocal.woCoreID);
});
```

or use a regular, counted `for` loop instead of `ListEach()` + `function`.

Comment: This. But I'd also caution that this also makes the anonymous function inside the `ListEach()` dependent on an external scope ( that can easily be changed outside the function and give an unexpected output ). Personally, I try to keep my functions as self-contained as I can make them. If I need it inside my function, then I explicitly send it there.

Comment: I went ahead and used the tried and true `FOR` loop and it resolved the issue. I wasn't aware of the ListEach until recently so I thought I'd try it. Clearly I need to read up on it more.